# INSERT has more target columns than expressions with loading JSON object

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run a simple insert script that will load in a json object into a postgresql db. I keep getting the following erorr message:

```
No data found
ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions
LINE 132: INSERT INTO books (title, author, genre, year, createdAt, up...
                                                         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 4152


CREATE TABLE Books (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, author VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, genre VARCHAR(255), year INTEGER, createdAt timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, updatedAt  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL)

WITH books_json (doc) AS (VALUES(
'[
    {
        "author": "Jane Austen",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-04 18:21:59.011 +00:00",
        "genre": "Classic",
        "title": "Emma",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-04 18:21:59.011 +00:00",
        "year": 1815
    }
]'::json))
INSERT INTO books (title, author, genre, year, createdAt, updatedAt)
SELECT p.* FROM books_json l CROSS JOIN lateral
json_populate_recordset(NULL::contacts, doc) AS p ON conflict (id)
do UPDATE SET name = excluded.name, active = excluded.active;
```

Comment: You probably want `json_populate_recordset(NULL::books, doc)` instead of `NULL::contacts`. I can't tell for sure that that's the cause of your error without seeing the table definition of contacts, but it seems safe to assume that `books` and `contacts` don't have the same columns :)

Comment: I have made the modification. now I'm getting: No data found
ERROR:  INSERT has more expressions than target columns
LINE 133: SELECT p.* FROM books_json l CROSS JOIN lateral
                 ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 4181 I think it is due to the fact that the column "year" is a builtin variable  in postgresql

Comment: If you think that is the case then do ```INSERT INTO books (title, author, genre, "year", createdAt, updatedAt)```. I think though that the ```CROSS JOIN``` is adding columns that you are not accounting for in the ```INSERT```. I would pull the ```SELECT``` out and run it to see what you are returning.

Comment: I renamed the column to "year1" , but it still showing the same error, so that does not appear to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.  I first expand the array into rows (in this case only one row) and then dereference and cast (if necessary) each key.

```
WITH books_json (doc) AS (VALUES(
'[
    {
        "author": "Jane Austen",
        "createdAt": "2018-10-04 18:21:59.011 +00:00",
        "genre": "Classic",
        "title": "Emma",
        "updatedAt": "2018-10-04 18:21:59.011 +00:00",
        "year": 1815
    }
]'::json)
), expand as (
  select json_array_elements(doc) as doc
   from books_json
)
insert into books (title, author, genre, year, createdat, updatedat)
select doc->>'title' as title,
       doc->>'author' as author,
       doc->>'genre' as genre,
       (doc->>'year')::int as year,
       (doc->>'createdAt')::timestamptz as createdat,
       (doc->>'updatedAt')::timestamptz as updatedat
  from expand;
```

Comment: your way works, but I just don't see the difference why your way would work and mine would not ~?

Comment: @user2371290 In my opinion, yours is made complicated by the reliance on the `contacts` rowtype as evidenced by the fact that you need to include that definition if you want help with solving it using a recordset transformation.  Further, it is more difficult to explain `lateral join` to developers I work with than to spell it out in a clear sequence of CTEs.

Comment: I got it straight from the docs. I think it is all boilerplate code. could you fill me as to why I have to declare year as int and also put the curly braces around year ie (doc->>'year')::int as year, but don't need to do that for title ,genre and author ?

Comment: @user2371290 The `->>` operator converts the value retrieved to `text`.  That value needs casting to `int` for year and `timestamptz` for the two date columns.

Comment: how come we don't need to cast the first 3 columns, ie genre, title and author?

Comment: @user2371290 Because `text` automatically converts to `varchar(255)` unless it is too long to fit.

Comment: @user2371290  So did this work for you, or should I delete it?